# Selenium Grid Node is repeatedly registering with the hub (Selenium 3.3)

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I run this command on a virtual machine to register a node with my Selenium Grid hub:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\geckodriver0-15-0.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://10.201.1.201:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer, version=10, platform=WINDOWS, maxInstances=5" -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS"
```

As a result, the node seems to connect correctly, but every minute or so I see

"Registering the node to the hub: [hub ip]
The node is registered to the hub and ready to use."

This doesn't seem to cause any errors with my tests, but I'm curious why it is repeatedly trying to register. I believe this started when I upgraded Selenium Server Standalone to 3.3.

I'm also noting that from my hub, I see that it keeps "marking the node as down because it can't be reached for 2 tries". Then it immediately registers that node again, and then it's down again, repeated forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3618) that should be fixed in version 3.3.1. It seemed to produce the same [problem you're seeing](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3631). If it still doesn't work I'd recommend commenting on the github issues.

Comment: Good call. Just upgraded from 3.3.0 to 3.3.1 and the issue is resolved. Thanks.